BlockNumber is no more availabe on frame_system
I updated my code to polkadot-v1.6.0,
its now gives error:
error[E0576]: cannot find associated type `BlockNumber` in trait `frame_system::Config`
  --> pallets/support/src/lib.rs:22:31
   |
22 |     <T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber,
   |     
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `frame_system::Config`


How to use the BlockNumber?
block: frame_system::Pallet::<T>::block_number(), block_number() has type BlockNumberFor<T>
frame_system::pallet::Pallet
pub fn block_number() -> BlockNumberFor<T>

Code link

Used
use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;

and
BlockNumberFor<T>,

